# What is the exact difference when you execute `git fetch upstream master:master` vs `git pull upstream master:master`

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

I know the difference between `git fetch` and `git pull`. `git pull` is basically a `git fetch` + `git merge` in one command.

However, I was researching on how to update my fork (master branch) with the upstream **without checking out the master branch**. I came across this SO answer - [Merge, update and pull Git branches without checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts/4157106#4157106)

But when I used `git fetch upstream master:master` after I was already checked out on master, I ran into this error -

```
fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository
```

So, I tried `git pull upstream master:master` and it worked. What is interesting is that doing `git pull upstream master:master` updates my fork with upstream **regardless of whether I am on master or not**. Whereas `git fetch upstream master:master` only works when I am **NOT on master** branch.

It will be very interesting to read explanation on this, from the knowledgeable folks out here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why "git fetch origin branch:branch" works only on a non-current branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028696/why-git-fetch-origin-branchbranch-works-only-on-a-non-current-branch)

Comment: Food for thought: [git fetch origin foo:bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26172920/7976758), [git pull origin master:master](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18787744/7976758).

Answer (score 4):

> `git pull` is basically a `git fetch` + `git merge` in one command

Yes—but, as you suspected, there is more to it than that.

[Bennett McElwee's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/merge-update-and-pull-git-branches-without-using-checkouts/4157106#comment62355072_4157106), in the answer you linked-to, actually has one of the key items.  He mentions that you can:

> Use `fetch origin branchB:branchB`, which will fail safely if the merge isn't fast-forward.

Another is not very well documented: it's the `-u` aka `--update-head-ok` option in `git fetch`, which `git pull` sets.  [The documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) does define what it does, but is a bit mysterious and scary:

> > By default *git fetch* refuses to update the head which corresponds
> >      to the current branch. This flag disables the check. This is purely
> >      for the internal use for *git pull* to communicate with *git fetch*,
> >      and unless you are implementing your own Porcelain you are not
> >      supposed to use it.

This gets us to your observation:

> So, I tried git `pull upstream master:master` and it worked. What is interesting is that doing `git pull upstream master:master` updates my fork with upstream regardless of whether I am on master or not. Whereas `git fetch upstream master:master` only works when I am NOT on master branch.

This is due to that `-u` flag.  If you ran `git fetch upstream master:master`, that would work, for some sense of the meaning *work*, but leave you with a different problem.  The warning is there for a reason.  Let's look at what that reason is, and see whether the warning is overly harsh.  Warning: there is a lot here!  Much of the complication below is to make up for historical mistakes, while retaining backwards compatibility.

#### Branch names, references, and fast-forwarding

First, let's talk about *references* and *fast-forward operations*.

In Git, a *reference* is just a fancy way of talking about a branch name like `master`, or a tag name like `v1.2`, or a remote-tracking name like `origin/master`, or, well, any number of other names, all in one common and sensible fashion: we group each specific *kind* of name into a [*name space*, or as a single word, namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace).  Branch names live under `refs/heads/`, tag names live under `refs/tags/`, and so on, so that `master` is really just `refs/heads/master`.

Every one of these names, all of which start with `refs/`, is a *reference*.  There are a few extra references that don't start with `refs` as well, although Git is a little bit erratic internally in deciding whether names like `HEAD` and `ORIG_HEAD` and `MERGE_HEAD` are actually references.<sup>1</sup>  In the end, though, a reference mainly serves as a way to have a useful name for a Git object hash ID.  Branch names in particular have a funny property: they *move* from one commit to another, typically in a way that Git refers to as a *fast forward*.

That is, given a branch with some commits, represented by uppercase letters here, and a second branch with more commits that include all the commits on the first branch:

```
...--E--F--G   <-- branch1
            \
             H--I   <-- branch2
```

Git is allowed to slide the *name* `branch1` forward so that it points to either of the commits that were, before, reachable only through the name `branch2`.<sup>2</sup>  Compare this, to, say:

```
...--E--F--G------J   <-- branch1
            \
             H--I   <-- branch2
```

If we were to move the name `branch1` to point to commit `I` instead of commit `J`, what would happen to commit `J` itself?<sup>3</sup>  This kind of motion, which leaves a commit behind, is a *non-fast-forward* operation on the branch name.

These names can be shortened by leaving off the `refs/` part, or often, even the `refs/heads/` part or the `refs/tags/` part or whatever.  Git will look in its reference-name database<sup>4</sup> for the first one that matches, using the six-step rules described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  If you have a `refs/tags/master` and a `refs/heads/master`, for instance, and say `master`, Git will match `refs/tags/master` first and use the tag.<sup>5</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>If a reference is a name that has, or can have, a *reflog*, then `HEAD` *is* a reference while `ORIG_HEAD` and the other `*_HEAD` names are not.  It's all a little fuzzy at the edges here, though.

<sup>2</sup>These commits might be reachable through more names.  The important thing is that they weren't reachable through `branch1` before the fast-forward, and are afterward.

<sup>3</sup>The immediate answer is actually that *nothing* happens, but eventually, if commit `I` is not reachable through *some* name, Git will *garbage collect* the commit.

<sup>4</sup>This "database" is really just the combination of the directory `.git/refs` plus the file `.git/packed-refs`, at least for the moment.  If Git finds both a file entry *and* a pathname, the pathname's hash overrides the one in the `packed-refs` file.

<sup>5</sup>Exception: `git checkout` tries the argument as a branch name *first*, and if that works, treats `master` as a *branch name*.  Everything else in Git treats it as a tag name, since prefixing with `refs/tags` is step 3, vs step 4 for a branch name.

---

#### Refspecs

Now that we know that a reference is just a name pointing to a commit, and a branch name is a specific kind of reference for which fast forwards are normal everyday things, let's look at the *refspec*.  Let's start with the most common and explainable form, which is just two *reference names* separated by a colon, such as `master:master` or `HEAD:branch`.

Git uses refspecs whenever you connect two Gits to each other, such as during `git fetch` and during `git push`.  The name on the left is the *source* and the name on the right is the *destination*.  If you are doing `git fetch`, the source is the *other* Git repository, and the destination is your own.  If you are doing `git push`, the source is your repository, and the destination is theirs.  (In the special case of using `.`, which means *this repository*, both source and destination are yourself, but everything still works just as if your Git is talking to another, separate Git.)

If you use fully-qualified names (starting with `refs/`), you know for sure which one you will get: branch, tag, or whatever.  If you use partially-qualified or unqualified names, Git will usually figure out what you mean anyway.  You will occasionally run into a case where Git *can't* figure out what you mean; in that case, use a fully qualified name.

You can simplify a refspec even further by omitting one of the two names.  Git knows which name you omit by which side of the colon is gone: `:dst` has no source name, while `src:` has no destination name.  If you write `name`, Git treats that as `name:`: a source with no destination.

What these *mean* varies.  An empty source for `git push` means *delete:* `git push origin :branch` has your Git ask their Git to delete the name entirely.  An empty destination for `git push` means *use the default* which is normally the same branch name: `git push origin branch` pushes your `branch` by asking their Git to set their branch named `branch`.<sup>6</sup>  Note that it's normal to `git push` to *their branch* directly: you send them your commits, then ask them to set their `refs/heads/branch`.  This is quite different from the normal `fetch`!

For `git fetch`, an empty destination means *don't update any of my references*.  A non-empty destination means *update the reference I supply.*  Unlike `git push`, though, the usual destination you might use here is a *remote-tracking name:* you would fetch their `refs/heads/master` into your own `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  That way, your branch name `master`—your `refs/heads/master`—is left untouched.

For historical reasons, though, the usual form of `git fetch` is just written as `git fetch remote branch`, omitting the destination.  In this case, Git does something seemingly self-contradictory:

- It writes the branch name update *nowhere*.  The lack of a destination means that no (local) branch gets updated.
- It writes the hash ID into `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.  Everything `git fetch` fetches always goes here.  This is where and how `git pull` finds out what `git fetch` did.
- It updates the remote-tracking name, such as `refs/remotes/origin/master`, even thought it was not told to do so.  Git calls this an *opportunistic update*.

(Much of this is actually controlled through a *default refspec* that you will find in your `.git/config` file.)

You can also complicate a refspec by adding a leading plus sign `+`.  This sets the "force" flag, which overrides the default "fast forward" check for branch name motion.  This is the normal case for your remote-tracking names: you want your Git to update your `refs/remotes/origin/master` to match their Git's `refs/heads/master` *even if* that's a non-fast-forward change, so that your Git always remembers where *their* `master` was, the last time your Git talked with their Git.

Note that the leading plus only makes sense if there is a destination to update.  There are three possibilities here:

- You're creating a new name.  This is generally OK.<sup>7</sup>
- You're making no change to the name: it used to map to commit hash *H* and the request says to set it to map to commit hash *H*.  This is obviously OK.
- You *are* changing the name.  This one breaks down into three more sub-possibilities:

  - It's not a branch-like name at all, e.g., it's a tag and should not move.  You will need a force flag to override the default rejection.<sup>8</sup>
  - It's a branch-like name, and the branch motion is a fast-forward.  You won't need the force flag.
  - It's a branch-like name, but the motion is *not* a fast-forward.  You will need the force flag.

This covers all the rules for updating references, *except* for one last rule, for which we need yet more background.

---

<sup>6</sup>You can complicate *this* by setting `push.default` to `upstream`.  In this case, if your branch `fred` has its upstream set to `origin/barney`, `git push origin fred` asks their Git to set their branch named `barney`.

<sup>7</sup>For various cases of updates, you can write hooks that do whatever you like to verify names and/or updates.

<sup>8</sup>In Git versions before 1.8.3, Git accidentally used branch rules for tag updates.  So this only applies to 1.8.3 and later.

---

#### HEAD is very special

Remember that a branch name like `master` just identifies some particular commit hash:

```
$ git rev-parse master
468165c1d8a442994a825f3684528361727cd8c0
```

You have also seen that `git checkout branchname` behaves one way, and `git checkout --detach branchname` or `git checkout hash` behaves another way, giving a scary warning about a "detached HEAD".  While `HEAD` acts like a reference in most ways, in a few, it's very special.  In particular, `HEAD` is normally a *symbolic reference*, in which it *contains the full name of a branch name*.  That is:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
```

tells us that the *current branch name* is `master`: that `HEAD` is attached to `master`.  But:

```
$ git checkout --detach master
HEAD is now at 468165c1d... Git 2.17
$ cat .git/HEAD
468165c1d8a442994a825f3684528361727cd8c0
```

after which `git checkout master` puts us back on `master` as usual.

What this means is that when we have a *detached HEAD*, Git knows which commit we have checked out, because the correct hash ID is right there, in the name `HEAD`.  If we were to make some arbitrary *change* to the value stored in `refs/heads/master`, Git would still know which commit we have checked out.

But if `HEAD` just contains the *name* `master`, the only way that Git knows that the *current* commit is, say, `468165c1d8a442994a825f3684528361727cd8c0`, is that `refs/heads/master` maps to `468165c1d8a442994a825f3684528361727cd8c0`.  If we did something that *changed* `refs/heads/master` to some other hash ID, Git would think that we have that other commit checked out.

Does this matter?  Yes, it does!  Let's see why:

```
$ git status
... nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git rev-parse master^
1614dd0fbc8a14f488016b7855de9f0566706244
$ echo 1614dd0fbc8a14f488016b7855de9f0566706244 > .git/refs/heads/master
$ git status
...
Changes to be committed:
...
        modified:   GIT-VERSION-GEN
$ echo 468165c1d8a442994a825f3684528361727cd8c0 > .git/refs/heads/master
$ git status
...
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Changing the hash ID stored in `master` changed Git's idea of the status!

#### The status involves HEAD vs index plus index vs work-tree

The `git status` command runs two `git diff`s (well, `git diff --name-status`es, internally):

- compare HEAD vs index
- compare index vs work-tree

Remember, the *index*, aka the *staging area* or the *cache*, holds the contents of the *current commit* until we start modifying it to hold the contents of the *next commit we will make*.  The work-tree is merely a minor helper for this whole *update the index, then commit* process.  We only need it because the files in the index are in the special Git-only format, that most of the programs on our systems cannot use.

If `HEAD` holds the raw hash ID for the current commit, then comparing `HEAD` vs index stays the same regardless of what we do with our *branch names*.  But if `HEAD` holds *one specific* branch name, and we *change* that one specific branch name's value, and then do the comparison, we'll compare a *different* commit to our index.  **The index and work-tree will be unchanged, but Git's idea of the *relative difference* between the (different) current commit and the index will change.**

This is *why* `git fetch` refuses to update the current branch name by default.  It's also why you cannot push to the current branch of a non-bare repository: that non-bare repository has an index and work-tree whose contents are *probably intended to match the current commit*.  If you change that Git's idea of what the current commit is, by changing the hash stored in the branch name, the index and work-tree are likely to stop matching the commit.

That's not fatal—not at all, in fact.  That's precisely what `git reset --soft` does: it changes the *branch name* to which `HEAD` is attached, without touching the contents in the index and the work-tree.  Meanwhile `git reset --mixed` changes the branch name *and* the index, but leaves the work-tree untouched, and `git reset --hard` changes the branch name, the index, and the work-tree all in one go.

#### A fast-forward "merge" is basically a `git reset --hard`

When you use `git pull` to run `git fetch` and then `git merge`, the `git merge` step is very often able to do what Git calls a *fast-forward merge*.  This is not a merge at all, though: it's a fast-forward operation on the *current branch name*, followed immediately by updating the index and work-tree contents to the new commit, the same way `git reset --hard` would.  The key difference is that `git pull` checks—well, is *supposed* to check<sup>9</sup>—that no in-progress work will be destroyed by this `git reset --hard`, while `git reset --hard` itself deliberately *does not* check, to let you throw away in-progress work that you no longer want.

---

<sup>9</sup>Historically, `git pull` keeps getting this wrong, and it gets fixed after someone loses a bunch of work.  Avoid `git pull`!

---

#### Putting all this together

When you run `git pull upstream master:master`, Git first runs:

```
git fetch --update-head-ok upstream master:master
```

which has your Git call up another Git at the URL listed for `upstream` and collect commits from them, as found via their name `master`—the left side of the `master:master` refspec.  Your Git then updates your own `master`, presumably `refs/heads/master`, using the right side of the refspec.  The `fetch` step would normally fail if `master` is your current branch—if your `.git/HEAD` contains `ref: refs/heads/master`—but the `-u` or `--update-head-ok` flag prevents the failure.

(If all goes well, your `git pull` will run its second, `git merge`, step:

```
git merge -m <message> <hash ID extracted from .git/FETCH_HEAD>
```

but let's finish with the first step first.)

The fast-forward rules make sure that your `master` update is a fast-forward operation.  If not, the fetch fails and your `master` is unchanged, and the `pull` stops here.  So we're OK so far: your `master` is fast-forwarded if and only if that's possible given the new commit(s), if any, obtained from `upstream`.

At this point, if your `master` has been changed *and* it's your current branch, your repository is now out of sync: your index and work-tree no longer match your `master`.  However, `git fetch` has left the correct hash ID in `.git/FETCH_HEAD` as well, and your `git pull` now goes on to the reset-like update.  This actually uses the equivalent of `git read-tree` rather than `git reset`, but as long as it succeeds—given the pre-`pull` checks, it *should* succeed—the end effect is the same: your index and work-tree will match the new commit.

Alternatively, perhaps `master` is *not* your current branch.  Perhaps your `.git/HEAD` contains instead `ref: refs/heads/branch`.  In this case, your `refs/heads/master` is safely fast-forwarded the way `git fetch` would have done even without `--update-head-ok`.  Your `.git/FETCH_HEAD` contains the same hash ID as your updated `master`, and your `git pull` runs `git merge` to attempt a merge—which may or may not be a fast-forward operation, depending on the commit to which your branch name `branch` points right now.  If the merge succeeds, Git either makes a commit (real merge) or adjusts index and work-tree as before (fast-forward "merge") and writes the appropriate hash ID into `.git/refs/heads/branch`.  If the merge fails, Git stops with a merge conflict and makes you clean up the mess as usual.

The last possible case is that your `HEAD` is detached, but this works in the same way as for the `ref: refs/heads/branch` case.  The only difference is that the new hash ID, when all is said and done, goes straight into `.git/HEAD` rather than into `.git/refs/heads/branch`.