# How can I pull and merge in just one step?

Tags: git

Say I have 2 branches: `develop` and `feature-10`. I'm working on `feature-10` and once feature's development is done, I create a pull request.

When I get a merge conflict in PR creation, I do this (from `feature-10` branch):

```
$ git checkout develop
$ git pull origin develop
$ git checkout feature-10
$ git merge develop
```

Is it possible to pull `develop` and merge into `feature-10` in one step, instead of checkout and pull explicitly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the exact difference when you execute \`git fetch upstream master:master\` vs \`git pull upstream master:master\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49784394/what-is-the-exact-difference-when-you-execute-git-fetch-upstream-mastermaster)

Comment: In your case the command is `$ git pull origin develop:develop`.

Comment: @phd comment is correct, but I advise avoiding tricky stuff like this. Use `git fetch origin` to obtain all updates from `origin` into `origin/*`, then do individual `git merge` commands on individual branches that you care about. Mostly you won't even bother with a local `develop` branch at all when you work this way—you don't need a local `master` or `develop`, just your local `feature-10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sven Hakvoort points out, the series of Git operations you want could be done by making use of chaining Git commands and then setting it as an alias for convenient access.

Define the alias in your `.gitconfig` file:

```
[alias]
pullmerge = !git checkout $1 && git pull origin $1 && git checkout $2 && git merge $1
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
git pullmerge develop feature-10
```

Naturally, if there are any merge conflicts, the alias won't be a smooth operation.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. The commands are individual and can not be combined, you can chain them with the `&&` operator but it can't be done in one command.