# Git - pull another remote branch into my local branch

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

I have a branch called 'my-feature' which tracks remote branch 'origin/my-feature'.

I also have a main branch where all development activity goes (trunk). It's 'dev' and the remote tracking branch is 'origin/dev'.

I create 'my-feature' branch from 'dev' to start with.

I would like to pull all the latest updates from 'dev' branch into my local 'my-feature' branch. When I applied the following command, it failed.

```
$ git pull --rebase origin/dev
fatal: 'origin/dev' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How I can pull the remote branch changes into my local branch, if the above is incorrect?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Okay, My bad.

When I interpret the manual in this way, things become easier.

Provided that I've checked out the branch (`my-feature` I'm trying to work on:

`Git pull origin dev`

This means, "fetch updates from `origin`, and then merge latest from `origin/dev` into `my-feature` branch.

And to find out what `origin` means:

`git remote --verbose` gives out what `origin` is for push/pull.

Comment: I recommend `git pull origin dev:dev`. See [the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18787744/7976758).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to run like:

```
git pull --rebase origin dev
```